How do I fix the error "Tag found too low on page" if I can't change the location of the Google Tag Manager snippet in the code?
I have this client's page which seems to have an issue with Google Tag Manager. The error message is: Tag found too low on page. It says this can delay the loading of the Tags on the page.
Using the Google Tag Legacy Assistant, it's true that the Google Tag Manager takes a significant amount of time to be detected. This could cause issues with conversion tracking if users perform an action before the Tag Manager is active.
For privacy purpose, let's say the client's website is example.com. This site is hosted on WordPress. However, we have a separate site for the online store that's hosted on Shopify that uses the subdomain store.example.com.
The Tag Manager is installed on the whole Shopify website using the XO Insert Code extension. It has always worked well.
Now, the problem is only occurring on a specific unindexed landing page using the url store.example.com/black-friday-specials.
How can this be happening since the Tag Manager snippet is installed site wide? I don't even think that I have a way to change where the code is installed on the page.
What can I do to fix this?

Where is it actually loading in your page content?  Is it in the page head?  Do you use lots of other plug-ins that are inserting code above it?

Worth noting that there is an official Google app for this - https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/12183125?hl=en

@RichardB I believe there are quite a few other plug-ins yes. I'm trying to figure out a way to place GTM before all of them. The official Google app might be a good place to start.
